# SQL Query & VBA error

Tags: sql, vba

I keep getting this error:

```
BOF or EOF set tu True, or the current record has been deleted. The requested
operation requires a current record.
```

My Code:

```
    MyQuery = "Select Destinataire, SUM(" & Entete & ") AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] " _
         & "WHERE [DateMad] Between #" _
         & Format(date_deb, "yyyy/mm/dd") _
         & "# And #" & Format(date_fin, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" & Query3 & " Group By Destinataire"

         objRecordSet.Open MyQuery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

         Feuil3.Cells(1, Col) = Entete
         Feuil3.Cells(strLine, 2) = Entete2
         Feuil3.Cells(2, Col).Value = objRecordSet.Fields("NombreTotal").Value
```

i get the error on the last line

```
  Feuil3.Cells(2, Col).Value = objRecordSet.Fields("NombreTotal").Value
```

why did it asks me for an BOF or EOF since i'm asking the SUM? also how to get this query to work plz ? 
i cannot breathe with this debugging

Comment: the debug.print MyQuery give the following :
    Select Destinataire, SUM(NbCompteurElecNR) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] WHERE [DateMad] Between #2012/11/21# And #2012/11/26# And [Destinataire] = 'REL12' Group By Destinataire

Comment: i keep getting
BOF or EOF set tu True, or the current record has been deleted. The requested operation requires a current record.

Comment: Try a different title for your question, and see if you get some answers.

Comment: I think you will find your select statement matches no records, therefore the recordset is empty. That's how I'd interpret that error message anyway. Also Kim maybe onto something, I haven't touched VBA in years (because it is indeed evil he he) but you may need to objRecordSet.Read() or something to get to the first record of the recordset before you can access the field values, such are the perils of imperative programming :)

Comment: thx for the help guys,
@HollyStyles, i interpret it that way too , but the query seem correct i really dont know why it bug like that

Comment: Debug/print to get the exact query being run, and run that yourself. Any records?

Comment: the query is correctly written like that:
Select DISTINCT Destinataire, SUM(NbCompteurElecNR) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] WHERE [DateMad] Between #2012/11/21# And #2012/11/26# And [Destinataire] = 'REL12' Group By Destinataire

but i get the same error if i want to get further

Comment: Why did you create duplicate question? I've given an answer to your problem in your second question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197468/sql-query-vba-error/13198330#13198330

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering on specific data (`Destinataire = 'REL12'`), and you are including that field in your query along with the sum, if there are no records, instead of getting one record with a sum of 0, you will get no data.

If you are getting the sum for a specific `Destinataire`, you don't need to include that field in your select or in your group by.  You are already filtering on just one `Destinataire`.

```
MyQuery = "Select SUM(" & Entete & ") AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] " _
     & "WHERE [DateMad] Between #" _
     & Format(date_deb, "yyyy/mm/dd") _
     & "# And #" & Format(date_fin, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" & Query3
```