# SQL Query & VBA error

Tags: sql, vba, ado

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Query & VBA error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197011/sql-query-vba-error)

i'm keep getting this error:

BOF or EOF set tu True, or the current record has been deleted. The requested operation requires a current record.

```
    MyQuery = "Select Destinataire, SUM(" & Entete & ") AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] " _
         & "WHERE [DateMad] Between #" _
         & Format(date_deb, "yyyy/mm/dd") _
         & "# And #" & Format(date_fin, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" & Query3 & " Group By Destinataire"

         objRecordSet.Open MyQuery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

         Feuil3.Cells(1, Col) = Entete
         Feuil3.Cells(strLine, 2) = Entete2
         Feuil3.Cells(2, Col).Value = objRecordSet.Fields("NombreTotal").Value
```

i get the error on the last line

```
  Feuil3.Cells(2, Col).Value = objRecordSet.Fields("NombreTotal").Value
```

why did it asks me for an BOF or EOF since i'm asking the SUM? also how to get this query to work plz ? 
i cannot breathe with this debugging

the debug.print MyQuery give the following :

```
 Select Destinataire, SUM(NbCompteurElecNR) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] WHERE [DateMad] Between #2012/11/21# And #2012/11/26# And [Destinataire] = 'REL12' Group By Destinataire
```

Comment: Have you checked that you have any records in that date range for REL12?

Comment: good find Remou, i didnt check the date and it take november and i have no records there
thx alot Remou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to comment on your data but you recieve an EOF error because your query (MyQuery) does not result in any rows of data. After you have opened your record set with your query, you must first check that it contains any rows before continuing (ie. it is not already at the end of the file 'EOF'). See below for example.

```
MyQuery = "....."

Set objRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
objRecordSet.Open MyQuery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

If Not objRecordSet.EOF Then
    'The record set contain one or more rows, do stuff
Else
    'The record set does not contain any rows, take action and notify user
End If

objRecordSet.Close
Set objRecordSet = Nothing
```

If your in the middle of an update/insert operation, you should do a proper rollback of the database in the event that you get an DB error or something else fails, otherwise you can leave the database in an unpleasant state. See below for example.

```
On Error Goto Rollback

objConnection.BeginTrans

MyInsertQuery = "..."

Set objRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
objRecordSet.Open MyInsertQuery , objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

objRecordSet(1) = someValue
objRecordSet(2) = someOtherValue
objRecordSet.Update

objRecordSet.Close
Set objRecordSet = Nothing

objConnection.CommitTrans

Exit Sub

Rollback:
    objConnection.RollbackTrans
    objRecordSet.Close
    Set objRecordSet = Nothing
```